# In cartodb, how can I insert a new row in a table via API?

Tags: sql, carto, api

We've discovered cartodb and we want to use it in our project, but in the API documentation we've only seen the sql.execute() method ([docs](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-6-1)) in order to insert a now row in a table.

Is this the way to insert points dynamically in our map?

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute write queries from the javascript client code, in order to insert a point in a table you need to write your own backend server, like:

```
http://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=INSERT INTO test_table (column_name, column_name_2, the_geom) VALUES ('this is a string', 11, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-110, 43),4326))&api_key={Your API key}
```

or use postgres functions with security definers:

http://blog.cartodb.com/post/53510434258/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin

Comment: Hi Javi, thanks for your answer. But if I invoke correctly this API url you're giving to me with $.ajax.post() for example, I would be invoking a write query from my javasript client code, wouldn't I? :-)

Comment: @josal If you do that from client side you will expose the api_key to everyone and that's something you don't want to do (except really special cases)

Comment: It's true. So, the process would be to do this call from my backend, perfect. Now I understand. http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html. Thanks!